# "Shallow" test requests underlying modules. Why does it go deeper?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme, jestjs

If I understand right the shallow test must not go deeper the the module which is been tested. Why do I get the displayed error?

[image]

App.js looks like:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './css/app.css';
import Router from './Router';
import Map from './containers/Map';
import MainTools from './components/ui/MainTools';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Map />
        <MainTools />
        <Router />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

MapActions.tsx is used inside Map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mount the children components but it still is going to import the files and when it hits an import it can't find there will still be an error. You are probably trying to import an object that doesn't exist.